# get back value from Hashed value?

Tags: c#, database, passwords, hashcode

I am trying to get back a string from its hash value?

```
string str="Hello";
int hashStr=str.GetHashCode(); // hash value of "Hello" is -694847
```

can I get back my_string (i.e "Hello") form the hashed value....?

**UPDATED**

actually i am thinking to save password into my database after hashing to make it secure...

So it means a different password even have same value?

Comment: Your tags don’t match the question. The `GetHashCode` has got **nothing** to do with encryption. In particular, it’s not a hash code that is suited in cryptography (neither a as a one-way hash nor as a code).

Comment: how do you think it is possible if string of *any* length is hashed to 4 bytes?

Comment: Hashing to make it secure requires using a cryptographic hash(preferably salted and using a standard KeyDerivateFuntion), and not something like GetHashCode. It is easy to find a string with any given GetHashCode. And in addition it's only a 32bit hash, which is susceptible to bruteforce.

Comment: The whole point of saving a hashed password is that no-one can get out the original plaintext!

Comment: No that's not the whole point, another point is that nobody can find another plaintext with the same hash either.

Comment: It is great idea to hash passwords, but **never ever** use `GetHashCode` for it because it is insecure. use MD5 or SHA2,

Comment: @Code: Oh, indeed. Need more caffeine.
@Javed: theoretically yes, but hashes used for passwords are long enough (MD5 is 80 bits, SHA1 is 160 bits etc) that this is not a practical concern.

Comment: @Javed: A more realistic concern is that if you use the same hash for all passwords, two users might have the same password with the same value.  If you give each user a different salt, this issue goes away.  Two users with the same hash for different passwords is no more a concern than two users having the same password for different accounts.

Comment: @Anton md5 is 128 bit, not 80.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are exactly 2^32 many hash codes but way, way more `string`s. Thus, by the [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), there have to be multiple `string`s mapping to the same hash code. Therefore, an inverse map from hash code to `string` is impossible

Edit: Response to your update.

> actually i am thinking to save password into my database after hashing to make it secure...
>
> So it means a different password even have same value?

Yes, it is possible for two passwords to have the same hash. This is basically a restatement of the above. But you shouldn't use `GetHashCode` to hash the password. Instead, use something secure like [SHA-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2).

To go one step further, never try to roll your own your encryption/security etc. Find a library that does it for you.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: Yeah, I have no idea what possessed me to type "roughly" instead of "exactly." Seeking more caffeine now. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: Thanks for actually including the math principle which makes this impossible, rather than just asserting it. +1.

Comment: to make answer perfect you should add that it is possible to find string that matches hash by for example bruteforce, but you will never find is that original string or not.

Comment: Don't use plain SHA-2 as password hash. Use a standard key-derivation-function with a salt instead.

Answer (score 8):

> actually I am thinking to save password into my database after hashing to make it secure

You are not competent to implement this code.

That's nothing to feel bad about. I'm not competent to do so either, and I've studied security systems for years. By studying security systems I've learned that security systems are *insanely difficult* to get right, require *years of experience* and *detailed expertise of a complex domain*.  That's how I know I'm not competent.  The fact that you think that hashes might be reversible indicates to me that you are not a security professional.

My advice: **hire a security professional to do this task for you**. There is no point in spending good money to make a bad security system that doesn't actually protect your resources. Rather than rolling your own cheap system now and spending a lot more money on cleaning up the disaster later, spend a little more up front now and get a professional implementation.

Furthermore, **the documentation for GetHashCode specifically states that it is not suitable to be used for password hashing because the algorithm could be changed at any time**.  In fact the hash algorithm *did* change between CLR v1 and CLR v2, and that broke every single vendor who relied upon GetHashCode for a password hash who upgraded their system. GetHashCode is not *stable*, it is not *secure*, it is not *crypto strength* and it is not *based on any industry standard algorithm*.  **DO NOT UNDER ANY CIRCUMSTANCES use it for crypto hashing.**

Comment: Well, Microsoft did create some implementations of this stuff (i.e., ASP.NET membership).

Comment: Implementing password hashing using existing libraries is something most programmers should be able to do. But of course a complex system has many potential pitfalls, so a professional review is useful. But the whole system needs to get reviewed, and not only the password hashing.

Comment: There were vendors who relied on GetHashCode for a password hash!? I am **not** asking for names, but did you guys get any complaints from really big companies about this?

Comment: Amen to the first non-quoted sentence in this answer.  I've seen nonsense like this _way_ too often.  "We've implemented a password, it's stored in plaintext in the database."  AUGH!

Comment: @Brian: I know we did get complaints from companies that had stored password hashes based on the result of GetHashCode. I was not privy to who complained.

Answer (score 5):

One answer that is missing here is explaining to the OP that hashing is not encryption.  The terms hashing and cryptography are often confusing for junior programmers (myself included at one point) who need to deal with security for the first time.

- [From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_%28computing%29): A hash function is any well-defined procedure or mathematical function that converts a large, possibly variable-sized amount of data into a small datum, usually a single integer that may serve as an index to an array (cf. associative array). The values returned by a hash function are called hash values, hash codes, hash sums, checksums or simply hashes.
- [From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption): Encryption is the process of transforming information (referred to as plaintext) using an algorithm (called cipher) to make it unreadable to anyone except those possessing special knowledge, usually referred to as a key.

Edit for Update:

1. Yes. Though unlikely and highly dependent on the type of hash algorithm, hashing of two or more different pieces of data could yield the same value.
2. Password hashing is often used to secure passwords in a database. But, you cannot un-hash passwords. If you want to hash them you have to evaluate the hash values to make sure they match. Here's and ASP-specific strategy for hashing passwords. Here is [a good read](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/000217.htm), especially if you're working with web technologies

Comment: I would disagree with your comment the "the idea you want... is encryption". For password storage a secure hash based solution is preferable to encryption for many reasons. You should never need to decrypt a password, only check for a match.

Comment: @Steve: Agreed. The OP modified the question after my initial post. It turns out that he's actually trying to figure out how to deal with hashed passwords, not en/decrypting anything.

Answer (score 3):

Something not mentioned in here is you should salt your hashes.. yum yum.

What a salt is/does.

Lets say you get a hold of someone's DB full of hashed passwords. If they hashed with no salt, then "breaking" passwords would be as easy as downloading a large pre-hashed dataset of a crap-ton of strings.

If the hash from one string matches, then you have a good chance of knowing the password. Even if it's not the correct password, you can still log in with it since it gives the same hash.

This is where salting your hashes comes in. If you add a salt (aka pre-determined random string) to a password before it is hashed, then you can't just pre-hash a ton of strings

example.
No Salt:
Password: ABCD hashes into 1234EFG
Large list of pre-hashed strings hash a hash of 1234EFG, may or may not be ABCD, but it will still work.

With Salt:
Password: ABCD concat 0315927429 hashes into 43BCF1
Each password has a different salt, so you can't use one pre-computer hash lookup table, you'd have to re-compute the hashes for every password.

Re-computing would incredibly time consuming. Now, the salt doesn't have to be securely stored for it to add lots of this benefit. Even if you store the salt in the same table, it would be incredibly hard for anyone to make a hash lookup to try to reverse any one person's password.

To other responder: "One answer that is missing here is explaining to the OP that hashing is not encryption."

Hashes are sometimes refereed to as "One way encryption". This is a **bad** description and adds to the confusion you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, in general you can't do it as string to hash isn't a one-to-one function; infinite number of strings but only 2^32 ~ 4 billion hashes.  That said, you can do a dictionary attack against an unsalted hash.  Get a cluster of computers to calculate hashes for a wide variety of likely strings (e.g., dictionary words) and find a hash that matches.

Comment: You can do a dictionary attack against a salted hash, too.  It takes longer, but it is still quite feasable if your dictionary is somewhat small.  Now, if you go a step further and add key-strengthening, a dictionary attack will start becoming a bit tougher to perform.

Comment: Good point; a salted password isn't a panacea, but it makes the dictionary attack non-trivial as a black hat has to generate a rainbow table for every salt used.  Using high-entropy passwords (generating hash-table for a dictionary attack is difficult) and salted passwords is fairly straightforward to implement, and basically computationally free.  If your server potentially has many users logging-in and is CPU limited, key strengthening (e.g., making each password check take 1 CPU-second) could slow down your server considerably if CPUs are churning away calculating hashes.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is : **No**. The hash is just one way.

If you want to secure your password as you said in the update, hash it with a hashing algorithmic (MD5, SHA1, ...) then stored in the database. When you want to verify the password given by the user, just hash it and compared to the hash stored in the database.

Comment: Make sure there is a salt added to the password or you're vulnerable to dictionary attacks (as I mentioned in my answer).  E.g., if the password is "password1", calculate the hash of "a45b0password1" (which using SHA1 is 24dfadb599eede1d63c37f956ae1c3328fe821d2) and store the password as something like: sha1$a45b0$24dfadb599eede1d63c37f956ae1c3328fe821d2  Every password should have a random string in front of it.  That way dictionary attacks are computationally expensive and have to be done for every salt.  (Rather than only having to build one sha1 dictionary up of hashses to passwords).

Answer (score 0):

> actually i am thinking to save
>   password into my database after
>   hashing to make it secure...
>
> So it means a different password even
>   have same value?

1. `GetHashCode` is not a [Cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function), so it isn't really appropriate for this purpose.
2. Yes, different passwords will have the same value.  Even so, this still makes the user's passwords more secure, though this can safely be done client-side rather than server-side for improved protection.  The purpose of hashing passwords before storing them is to make sure your database* cannot be used to determine a user's passwords.  A user could still use the hashes stuck in your database to pose as your users, but knowing a user's actually site password is more valuable, since a good chunk of your users will use the same passwords everywhere else.

*There are other similar attacks this protects against like man-in-the-middle attacks, but in general it's all about ensuring you don't store a user's password in your database in plain text.

Comment: Agree that GetHashCode is not what he needs, but secure hashing is the way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use GetHashCode() to hash a password. It isn't a cryptographic hash and it's resulting hash way too short. GetHashCode is designed for use in HashTables and similar structures. A GetHashCode() which returns a constant value is valid(but slows down hashtables a lot).

For password-hashing there are several pitfalls:

- Use a salt, so an attacker can't use rainbowtables(or similar pre-calculation attacks)
- Use many iterations to slow down bruteforce attacks
- Use a cryptographic hashfunction

You better not implement it yourself, but instead use a standard Key Derivation Function (KDF) such as PBKDF2.

The .net framework contains classes to do this for you:

- [Rfc2898DeriveBytes implements PBKDF2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx)
- [PasswordDeriveBytes implements PBKDF1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.passwordderivebytes.aspx)

To check if the entered password is correct, you don't decrypt the saved password(which isn't possible), but you hash the entered password with the same salt as the original password, and then compare the hash.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get back value from hashed value, but what you can do (and this is what is done in almost every website that saves hashed passwords) is to compare the hash of the just-entered password to the hash you've saved.

And about your second question, it is true that there can be more than one text to match one hash, but it's not like the hash of "hello" is equals to the hash of "goodbye". It's more like the hash of "hello" is equals to the hash of "sdd89sfu7w84haushf9478hfsklehf84hfwuhf...".